# Create array from hierarchy javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested

Please if anyone can help me with the issue I'm struggling.

I have this hierarchy:

```
A
-Aname
-B
--Bname
--B1
---B1name
---B11
----B11name
--B2
---B2name
---B21
----B21name
-C
--Cname
--C1
---C1name
```

This means that A is parent of Aname and B, B is parent of Bname and B1, B1 of B1name and B11 etc.
How can I build a nested array using javascript recursion of this hierarchy looking like this:

```
[A[Aname, B[Bname, B1[B1name B11[B11name]], B2[B2name, B21[B21name]]], C[Cname, C1[C1name]]]]
```

Comment: How is the data initially represented?

Comment: It would help if you posted actual javascript. You are makin us guess that this is represented as something like an object. And then to give you an answer we have to recreate it.

Comment: Sorry, A, B, B1... are objects with name as property. 
There is another script that has objects that fills the data, but I don't have a insight there. All I need is to create a structure that will check if an object representation is a child of previous one and push them in the array so that it will look like the one I sent, together with a property of each object

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.

Comment: @programernc: You can edit your question to better describe your input and preferred output.  Please also explain what you've tried so far.  (There should be an `edit` link between the post and the comments.)

Comment: "so that it will look like the one I sent" The one you sent isn't valid javascript. What is `A` in that array? Is it a string? You won't get good answers here unless you are very specific and accurate about what you want. Post the *actual javascript* you are starting with and the *actual javascript* you want in the end.

Answer (score 4):

As what i understood, your input is like

```
var obj = {
    A: {    
        Aname: {},
        B:{
            Bname: {},
            B1:{}
        }
    }
};
```

and output is like

```
[["Aname",["Bname","B1"]]]
```

so here is your solution:

```
function rfun(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map(item=>{
        return Object.keys(obj[item]).length ? rfun(obj[item]) : item;
    })
}
```